# Java Matcher Pattern issue

Tags: java, pattern-matching, matcher

I am trying to extract everything that is after this string path `/share/attachments/docs/`. All my strings are starting with `/share/attachments/docs/`

For example: `/share/attachments/docs/image2.png`
Number of characters after ../docs/ is not static!

I tried with

```
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(.*)/share/attachments/docs/(\\d+)$");
   Matcher m = p.matcher("/share/attachments/docs/image2.png");
   m.find();         
   String link = m.group(2);    
   System.out.println("Link #: "+link);
```

But I am getting Exception that: `No match found.`
Strange because if I use this:

```
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(.*)ABC Results for draw no (\\d+)$");
   Matcher m = p.matcher("ABC Results for draw no 2888");
```

then it works!!!

Also one thing is that in some very rare cases my string does not start with `/share/attachments/docs/` and then I should not parse anything but that is not related directly to the issue, but it will be good to handle.

Comment: So you want to get `image2.png`?

Comment: Can you use String#startswith ?

Comment: What exactly is surprising about the fact that the sub-expression `(\\d+)` does not match the substring `"image2.png"`?

Comment: As @JohnBollinger pointed out `(\\d+)` is for numeric values, not string values like you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am getting Exception that: `No match found.`

This is because `image2.png` doesn't match with `\d+` use a more appropriate pattern like `.+` assuming that you want to extract `image2.png`.

Your regular expression will then be `^(.*)/share/attachments/docs/(.+)$`

---

In case of `ABC Results for draw no 2888`, the regexp `^(.*)ABC Results for draw no (\\d+)$` works because you have several successive digits at the end of your `String` while in the first case you had `image2.png` that is a mix of letters and digits which is the reason why there were no match found.

---

Generally speaking to avoid getting an `IllegalStateException: No match found`, you need first to check the result of [`find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--), if it returns `true` the input `String` matches:

```
if (m.find()) {
   // The String matches with the pattern
   String link = m.group(2);    
   System.out.println("Draw #: "+link);
}  else {
   System.out.println("Input value doesn't match with the pattern");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. Its working. But how I can be sure I will not receive exception if my string does not start with /share/attachments/docs/ ?

Comment: I tested now some random string and it does not work... Can it be checked with Matchern Pattern or not? Thanks

Comment: which String for example?

Comment: C:\Users\bvuddavic\Desktop\drugi.xls

Comment: You can see those are basically http or disk links and everything which is not within the default path should not be parsed

Comment: Thank you. I marked it as answer. So basically (.+) means it will extract everything which is after this first string correct? There are no any restrictions for example: blank space, slashes, backslashes etc...? is this true? Thank you

Comment: . means "any character but line terminators by default" and + means at least one so .+ means at least one character that is not a line terminator. If you want to include line terminators, you will have to enable dotall mode see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL

Comment: I tested your example and it works. However if i put as Matcher Matcher m = p.matcher("C:\Users\john.smith\Desktop\image2.jpg"); then it does not work but it throws exception. This is what I meant by rare cases that sometimes is link the user path on the desktop computer and then I should not try to parse the string at all!!! But if value is some not so appropriate value but user's disk path on the computer then it does not work. Can you try with it?

Comment: If I use C:\Users\john.smith\Desktop\image2.jpg with the new code, I get Input value doesn't match with the pattern as expected, I don't get any exception

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression `\d+` (expressed as `\\d+` inside a string literal) matches a run of one or more *digits*.  Your example input does not have a corresponding digit run, so it is not matched.  The regex metacharacter `.` matches *any* character (+/- newline, depending on regex options); it seems like that may be what you're really after.

Additionally, when you use `Matcher.find()` it is unnecessary for the pattern to match the whole string, so it is needless to include `.*` to match leading context.  Furthermore, `find()` *returns a value* that tells you whether a match to the pattern was found.  You generally want to use this return value, and in your particular case you can use it to reject those rare non-matching strings.

Maybe this is more what you want:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/share/attachments/docs/(.+)$");
Matcher m = p.matcher("/share/attachments/docs/image2.png");
String link;

if (m.find()) {
    link = m.group(1);
    System.out.println("Draw #: " + link);
} else {
    link = null;
    System.out.println("Draw #: (not found)");
}
```

Comment: Hi John , I tested your example and it works. However if i put as Matcher  Matcher m = p.matcher("C:\Users\john.smith\Desktop\image2.jpg");  then it does not work but it throws exception. This is what I meant by rare cases that sometimes is link the user path on the desktop computer and then I should not try to parse the string at all!!!

Comment: Can you help me with this for full answer?

Comment: @Dejan, "C:\Users\john.smith\Desktop\image2.jpg" is not a valid Java String literal.  Double the backslashes.  As you wrote it, I could believe that you get a *compile* error, but not that the code I presented throws an exception.

Comment: @Dejan, in any event, "not try to parse the string at all" is inconsistent with checking the form of the string.  If you know without looking at its contents that the string is not one you should parse, then don't in that case execute the code that parses it.  If you need to check the string to determine that, then that *is* parsing it.